# Selenium HtmlUnitDriver gives "geb.navigator.EmptyNavigator' is not present" error although Firefoxdriver works fine

Tags: selenium-webdriver, spock, geb, selenium-firefoxdriver, htmlunit-driver

I am performing a simple GUI test using Geb/Spock and Selenium.

My Spec :

```
class MySpecSpec  extends LoggedInSpec {

def "My criteria here"() {
    given: "Starting at the unit search entry page"
    to MyHomePage

    when:
    def result = statusSelection("DEALER_STOCK")

    then: "The status selection should be set to dealer stock"
    result
}}
```

And My Page Object:

```
class MyHomePage extends MyContextPage {

@Override
String getPageUrl() {
    return super.getPageUrl() + "/unt/overviewMenu.html"
}
//check if csv button exist
static at = { $('.buttons-csv').text() != '' }
static content = {
    statusSelection { value -> $("select[id=searchSelection] option[value='${value}']") }
    filterButton(to: UnitSearchHomePage) { $('a[id=searchMy]') }
    resetButton { $('a[id=resetStock]') }
    addUnitToStockButton { $('a[id=addUnitBtn]') }
}}
```

When I run MySpec,using `driver = {new HtmlUnitDriver(javascriptEnabled: true)}`

I get

***geb.error.RequiredPageContentNotPresent: The required page content 'model.unt.MyHomePage -> statusSelection(DEALER_STOCK): geb.navigator.EmptyNavigator' is not present***

Although using firefox driver works fine. `driver = { new FirefoxDriver() }`

Below is the pom.xml excerpt for versions:

```
  <gebVersion>1.0</gebVersion>
  <seleniumVersion>2.53.1</seleniumVersion>
  <seleniumHtmlUnitVersion>2.52.0</seleniumHtmlUnitVersion>
  <org.codehaus.groovy-all.version>2.4.3</org.codehaus.groovy-all.version>
  <org.codehaus.gmaven.version>1.5</org.codehaus.gmaven.version>
```

Thanks in advance.